# how to configure x-ray traces for amazon-neptune?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-neptune, aws-xray

I've an api going thru Lambda (node.js) to Aws Neptune. X-ray shows the traces from api-gateway --> lambda and stops here. Has anyone enabled deeper tracing all the way into Neptune ?

Thanks !

Comment: Hi Sahas, was there anything else you'd like clarified? If not, do you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use AWS X-Ray SDK for Node.js to instrument your lambda function so the calls to Neptune are traced: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-awssdkclients.html

Please let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the most you can do is to use XRay clients and explicitly trace [1] the requests that you make from your Lambda. Neptune's AWS SDK currently only tracks management API calls, and not queries to the database. So unlike the dynamo db example called out in XRay docs, you cannot get granular insights (eg: query that was executed, the latency breakdowns etc) via XRay from Neptune at the moment.

It does sound like a useful feature, so I would recommend making a feature request for the same, or build something custom for the client you are using. Just curious, what client are you using from within the lambda? (ie Gremlin GLV? Raw HTTP request? Jena? etc..) For example, if you're using Gremlin GLV, then maybe all you need is to build a custom netty handler that can do tracing on your behalf.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-httpclients.html